# Text file not appearing in correct path location when executing batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

It's my first time writing scripts for a college course I'm taking. I'm trying to write a simple batch script that creates a new folder, saves all the system IP configurations to a text file INSIDE that folder, and then pings the network and appends the text file with the results. any reason why this code

```
@echo off
md tempinfo
ipconfig /all > C:\Users\MyUser\tempinfo\output.txt
ping (IP address) >> C:\Users\MyUser\tempinfo\output.txt
```

is creating a tempinfo folder with nothing in it? I know the ipconfig and ping commands are working but I cannot get the text file to show up inside the tempinfo folder.

Comment: `md "%UserProfile%\tempinfo" 2>nul` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe /all > "%UserProfile%\tempinfo\output.txt"` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 >> "%UserProfile%\tempinfo\output.txt"` would solve the problem. The command `md tempinfo` creates the directory in the __current directory__ which can be any directory depending on which directory was set as current directory by the process starting `cmd.exe` for processing the batch file.

Comment: Please look on the list of predefined [Windows environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) and open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window, run the command `set` and look on the output list of environment variables with their names defined by the Windows shell (`explorer.exe`) for your account.

Comment: Have you tried removing ```C:\Users\MyUser\``` from lines `3` and `4`?, or better yet, changing line `2` to ```md C:\Users\MyUser\tempinfo```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like that :

```
@echo off
If not exist "%UserProfile%\tempinfo" MD "%UserProfile%\tempinfo"
(
    ipconfig.exe /all
    ping.exe 127.0.0.1
)>"%UserProfile%\tempinfo\output.txt"
if exist "%UserProfile%\tempinfo\output.txt" Start "" /MAX "%UserProfile%\tempinfo\output.txt"
```